# How to fill row value based on condition of a string?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

If I have a dataframe like so:

```
Match             Score  Result
Team A vs Team B  1:2  Team A
Team B vs Team C  2:2  Draw
Team C vs Team A  4:0  Team C
```

How can I determine/fill in the `Result` column based on score from the `Score` column?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.apply()` with custom function:

```
def get_result(x):
    s1, s2 = map(int, x["Score"].split(":"))
    t1, t2 = x["Match"].split(" vs ")
    if s1 == s2:
        return "Draw"
    elif s1 > s2:
        return t1
    return t2


df["Result"] = df.apply(get_result, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              Match Score  Result
0  Team A vs Team B   1:2  Team B
1  Team B vs Team C   2:2    Draw
2  Team C vs Team A   4:0  Team C
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I learned something new myself!